# How to transfer Google Chrome history to new machine

Tags: macos, google-chrome, migration-assistant

I moved to a new Mac using Migration Assistant and everything worked perfectly until I realized that I had no browsing history in Chrome (my bookmarks and auto-completion info transfered ok).

So I would like to know if there is a way I can manually transfer my history to the new Mac.

Answer (score 5):

I would think that Chrome's history is stored in `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`. Try copying that folder from your original Mac to the new Mac. Just make sure you back up the version of the folder on the new Mac just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Isn't Application Support supposed to be copied when using Migration Assistant?

Comment: I think so, but just in case it didn't work properly it wouldn't hurt to try again. The history should be stored there...

Comment: @DanielBeck I just used migration assistant and all chrome addons are missing from Chrome (I'm not sure if they're in the file system somewhere and Chrome can't 'see' them or if they're outright missing). I looked in `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` and see around 100 files

Comment: @DanielBeck I got them back, I just had to 'Sync' chrome

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to sign in to Chrome with a Google account, then Google keeps settings, bookmarks, history etc in the cloud.

Comment: I have **Web & App Activity** turned on, but [My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) doesn't show all of my browsing history.

Answer (score -1):

The answer for me was to click in the very top right of chrome and turn on "Sync"

As soon as I did that, 20 seconds alter, all my old extensions appeared.

Comment: This question is about transferring browsing history, not extensions.